# ERROR: Type 'StoreViewController' does not conform to protocol 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver'

Tags: ios, swift, skpaymenttransaction

I keep getting an Error message (Type `StoreViewController` does not conform to protocol `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`) I have reviewed the code several times. Perhaps I need a set of fresh eye or there is something actually wrong with the coding - which I feel is more likely.

I had to add a number of closing curly brackets at the end of the code to reduce the number of errors down to one. But after that it goes up again if I try. Thus perhaps it may not be a curly brace issue.

Please help me with the solution or rather locate my Error. (Xcode 9.3)

```
import UIKit

import StoreKit

class StoreViewController: UIViewController , SKPaymentTransactionObserver , SKProductsRequestDelegate {


        @IBOutlet weak var storeLabel: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var buyButton: UIButton!

        @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!

        var product: SKProduct?

        var productID = "com.Haleemani.SilkyDragon.removeads"


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        }

        @IBAction func dimissView(_ sender: Any) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        @IBAction func purchase(_ sender: Any) {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product!)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

        }

        func getPurchaseInfo() {
            if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

                let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(objects: self.productID) as! Set<String>)

                request.delegate = self
                request.start()

            } else {

                storeLabel.text = "Unsuccessful"
                infoLabel.text = "Check your settings and try again"

            }

        }

        func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
            var products = response.products
            if (products.count == 0) {

                storeLabel.text = "Unsuccessful"
                infoLabel.text = "Cheack your settings and try again"
            } else {

                product = products [0]
                storeLabel.text = product!.localizedTitle
                infoLabel.text = product!.localizedDescription
                buyButton.isEnabled = true

                let invalids = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

                for product in invalids {
                    print ("product not found: \(product)")

                }
            }
        }

        func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
            for transaction in transactions {

                switch transaction.transactionState {

                case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                    storeLabel.text = "Thank You"
                    infoLabel.text = "You have removed Watermark in all your images Forever"
                    buyButton.isEnabled = false

                case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                    storeLabel.text = "Thank You"
                    infoLabel.text = "You have removed Watermark in all your images Forever"

                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: may be you have 1 more } at the bottom of the file

Comment: You do not have the closed comma in "com.Haleemani.SilkyDragon.removeads”. The " is not a same with the ”

Comment: Your declaration of `func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` is inside another func `productsRequest(_: didReceive:)`. Move it out.

Comment: Select all code and Press Control I to format the indentation and that would help you identify the mistake

Comment: the answer by OOPer was correct. I had to close the func paymentQueue and remove one curly brace from the end. Thank you for all your answers. I appreciate it #blessU